# call method to be implemented in subclass from base class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

```ts
//BaseClass.ts

class Base {
  connstructor() {}

  callSubClassMethod = () => {
    return this.subMethod();
  }

}


//SubClass.ts

class Sub extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  subMethod = () => {
    console.log('Iam subclass method')
  }
}
```

Is this possible in typescript?
the base class complains that **subMethod** is not defined.
This works without the class encapsulation, I have been looking for a way around this as majority of my codebase is in ES6+ syntax

Comment: Define subMethod in the base class (it can be a noop that just does a `return` if you want) and then override it in the subclass to create the actual implementation.  In a typed language, you can't call a method that isn't defined in your class or a parent class.

Comment: Imagine having an object of type Base and calling callSubClassMethod on it? What would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Base` class implementation relies on a method that is not (and cannot be) defined, then `Base` is `abstract` and should be declared as such:

```
abstract class Base {

  abstract subMethod(): any;

  callSubClassMethod = () => {
    return this.subMethod();
  }

}
```

If the method *can* be defined, so that it performs some default action or returns some default value, then simply define it in `Base`:

```
class Base {

  subMethod() {
      // do some default thing, for example, nothing
  }

  callSubClassMethod = () => {
    return this.subMethod();
  }

}
```